# In an array of hashes, how to remove a value that is already present in another key?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How do I remove a value that is already present in another key?

For example:

I have a tabulated file, `File_A`:

```
a   1
b   4
c   1
a   2
b   5
c   6
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while (File_A) {
    push {@{$hash{$File_A[0]}, $File_A[1]}};
}

So that my %hash is equal to this
%hash = (
    a => [ '1','2'],
    b => [ '4','5'],
    c => [ '1','6'],
);
```

The value `1` is present in both keys `a` and `c`. Is there a way where I can prevent a duplicate value from being pushed into the 
array of hashes so that it looks like this?

```
%hash = (
   a => [ '1','2'],
   b => [ '4','5'],
   c => [ '6'],
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each new value you need to check whether it's been seen. For this purpose all unique values should be recorded separately, to make it efficient and easy to check a new value against them.

Then use a hash to store seen values as keys, since it only takes a lookup to check whether a key exists. If it doesn't then process (add data to your results etc), and add that key to the hash with the ones already seen.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $file = shift || 'File_A';

my (%result, %seen);

open my $fh_A, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh_A>) { 
    my ($key, $val) = split;

    next if exists $seen{$val};   # saw this value already, skip

    push @{$result{$key}}, $val;

    $seen{$val} = 1;
}

dd \%result;
```

I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to see complex data.  If installing this is a problem use core [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)

Comment: I see! Thanks zdim! Quick question, why do you need to set the value of $seen{$val} to 1?

Comment: @cms72  That's how we keep track of what's been seen -- we add the value just seen as a key to that hash (then it's easy to use `exists` to check every new value).  The value for the key doesn't have to be `1` if that's what you mean, it can be anything (an empty string `''` or `undef` would work for instance), but we have to assign _something_ for that new key.  I just thought a `1` makes good sense :)

Comment: @cms72 Welcome :)  Let me know if explanations (and which) are needed/can help